# Travel in Spain before Student Visa start date

Tags: visas

I have a student visa to study in Spain with a "valid from" date of Jan 8.  I am travelling to Spain from US on Dec 21.  I know I need to leave Spain and go to non-Schengen country (Morocco or UK) and then re-enter Spain at some point to activate student visa.  Do I have to leave Spain before Jan 7 or just within 90 days?

Comment: Are you a US citizen? If so, that sounds weird, given that my daughter arrived in Spain before the start of the university semester (before the 'valid from' on the student visa) and had no problems at the border.

Comment: yes - US citizen.  Spanish consulate actually told me I had to leave Spain before "valid from" date and then re-enter, but I've seen blogs that say I would just have to leave within 90-day tourist window.